# Does paragraph length follow a normal distribution?

Tags: paragraphs, statistics

Many naturally occurring things follow a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

I'm curious to know if paragraphs follow a normal distribution too?

Note: paragraph length could be measured in characters, or words.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, while interesting, this does not relate to English usage at sentence level or below, and where it overlaps with how English is actually used concerns style rather than more rigorous matters. // [Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-paragraph-length-1691481#:~:text=%22In%20modern%20academic%20writing%2C%20paragraphs,to%20twenty%20lines%20in%20length.) gives useful information.

Comment: An interesting question, not about usage, so reasonably closed. Nevertheless I point out that the normal distribution is unbounded on each side, whereas paragraph length is bounded at the small end by zero (or close to zero, anyway). A normal distribution is certainly not the answer. You need an assymmetrical distribution instead. Try looking at the Poisson, log-normal, Weibull, Gamma function distributions.

Comment: As others have noted, a very interesting question, but just not appropriate for ELU (it all depends on the selection of things you're studying. You might have paragraphs of a particular author or of a particular genre. Also, presumably word or character length is your statistic, which are counts, so the most common relevant distributions are Poisson, geometric, negative binomial. For a better real answer, check out [stats.se]. or [datascience.se]

Comment: @Anton *not about usage* - are you sure? I programmed an AI to generate text, and wish for it to be as "human" as possible. Initially, I used a [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) for paragraph lengths (a random sample of between 2-7 sentences), but with the new information below I'll instead use a [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), since it better characterises human use of English. The connection's there, just not obvious at first.

Comment: Voting to reopen because it seems to me that the way people use language includes the paragraph length property.

Comment: 1) It can't be log-normal as that is a continuous distribution and paragraph length is discrete. 2) Any of these distributions come with parameters (eg mean or variance) which will be specific to the language/author/style/set of texts. 3) Pick your distribution and params judiciously and check if the paragraphs seem reasonable and that'll be fine for generation... like who will notice? 4) you probably still want an upper cutoff. A run-on paragraph can be hard to read. 5) If you want to -actually- understand... ask over at [stats.se] or [datascience.se]

Comment: @Mitch it’s a shame it’s closed or else you/others could make an answer.

Comment: @stevec I believe it is off topic on ELU (there is way too much variation to say, also it depends on author's writing style). But it is very much on topic on those other sites and If no one else answers it there, I might. You may also want to ask on [ai.se] since this is kind of a programming question. [stas.se] will explain all the assumptions in your question that you don't realize you're making. Are you familiar with the [Zipf distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law)?... your question is very much in the same vein.

Answer (score 3):

I took a look at character lengths of paragraphs in Jane Austin's six major novels. That's by no means representative of English literature generally, but it's a start ([here](https://gist.github.com/stevecondylios/b24e1f3c70a386d13450d575e8423ae6) is reproducible R code). Here are the results.

First, here is the count of characters in paragraphs in every paragraph of all 6 novels:

[image]

Since it appears as though some extremely long paragraphs may skew right, this examines what happens when the longest 1% of paragraphs are excluded from the plot:

[image]

And this looks at what happens when the longest 10% are excluded (it's getting *more* normal, and starts to exhibit some normal-*ish* characteristics (mode in the center, mostly monotonic increasing on the left of mode, mostly monotonic decreasing to the right of mode), it would be best described as a [*log-normal distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) (thanks [@
schrödingcöder](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/589892/does-paragraph-length-follow-a-normal-distribution#comment1480380_589896)).

[image]

Comment: Not what one would call a normal distribution. Incidentally, Austen produced revised editions of some of her novels; they might be interesting to study too.

Comment: Hardly a representative sample, and certainly not of modern usage, stevec (I'd suspect Chandler's barcharts might be of very different shape). And importantly, I believe off-topic here (though a fascinating question).

Comment: I imagine that the results would be very different with news articles (for example), which often include many one-sentence paragraphs. And if you included emails, social media posts, blogs, marketing copy, . . . OP's question was really quite broad.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan very much agree. The use of Jane Austin texts was somewhat arbitrary. I like your idea of using blogs, perhaps someone could retrieve 1000 or so New Yorker or Economist articles and make similar plots for them, it would be interesting.

Comment: @JohnLawler Seems more like a log-normal distribution

Comment: @schrödingcöder you are right. I included (and attributed) your additional information in the answer.